# Google Javascript API not sending request ~30 seconds after document is loaded in a windows service

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps-api-3, vb6, windows-services

I have a weird problem where after around 30+ seconds after a local html page has finished loading, calling the google AutocompleteService or PlacesService javascript function does not send out a request to do the lookup. But if less than 30 seconds it works fine. I can even do multiple successful calls if within that time.

### Background:

We have a C# dll that is used by a VB6 app that runs as a Windows service. The dll is used to do autocomplete and other places API lookups through the Javascript API.
Due to the asynchronous nature of the google lookups, the WebBrowser control lives in its own thread with its own message loop eg.

```
thrd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
    delegate
    {
       Init(false);
       System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(this);
    }));
 // set thread to STA state before starting
 thrd.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
 thrd.Start();
```

This is all setup once as part of the startup process of the service.

This dll works fine elsewhere which includes apps running in IIS and on the desktop.

### Troubleshooting:

1. I confirmed that the browser thread stays alive on subsequent lookup calls from the windows service.
2. Through debugging, i can see that the javascript function (below) is being run (i can see the debug outputs) with no errors thrown. However, the google call, **autocomplete.getPlacePredictions**, does not send anything out (our network guy was monitoring the traffic while i did the lookup)

Example of the javascript function:

```
     function doAutoComplete(waitKey, searchString, latBias, longBias,     radiusBias, components, typesFilter) {

        //Removed irrelevant code to keep it brief

        //debug output here

        autocomplete.getPlacePredictions(options, function (waitKey) {
            return (function (predictions, status) {
                window.external.setResult(waitKey, status, JSON.stringify(predictions));
            });
        } (waitKey));

        //debug output here
    }
```

3. The service does not have the issue when installed to a windows 7 machine. So at this stage the issue only happens in a Windows 2012 Server machine.

I have run out of ideas as to what could be causing the google call to not work.

Any help or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

### Edit history:

1. Added #3 to Troubleshooting.

Comment: See this JSFiddle for an example usage of getPlacePredictions [http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/mFgdw/](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/mFgdw/)

Comment: The javascript code above is just a snippet, but it definitely works so no problem with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted it out.
The issue was that the IE enchanced security configuration (IE ESC) was internally blocking/disabling the call to Google. Turning it off prevents the issue from happening but i will look further into tweaking it rather than turning it off.

What is annoying is that it was doing it silently so was hard to track down. I believe the issue only happened when running as a windows service because of the different security levels used for it versus running from the desktop or IIS.